# can't find openCV head file

Tags: c++, opencv

Recently I'm learning openCV. I followed the tutorial on openCV website. 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv

However, when I compile my code using following command

```
g++ loadImage.cpp -o loadImage
```

the command line shows:

```
fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
     ^
```

I installed openCV with brew, I think it is OK. Then I use emacs to edit and g++ compile my code directly, is that the problem? I searched some similar problems but they refer to xCode environment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell g++ where it can find the header files. I recommend you setup either eclipse or any other IDE that can handle that stuff for you (like Qt Creator or many others). You can follow the setup guides for OpenCV for instructions, if needed.

[edit: note that I know that emacs can also be setup to handle things like include and library paths, but I have no idea how, hence my recommendation for a full scale IDE]

You can also specify the path to the includes on the command line with `-I`, then it should also work. Example:

```
g++ -I/path/to/OpenCV-2.4.9/build/include loadImage.cpp -o loadImage
```

There are environment variables you can set so you don't have to specify this for every call (see [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) for a complete list, specifically `CPATH` and it's variants might be of interest.

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll try to use an IDE, though I still prefer to train myself to use EMACS only :)

Comment: Well, many people use emacs as an IDE, so it should be rather trivial to google how to set it up for compiling and debugging c++. At the very least use a makefile-like system (make, cmake, ant, ...) to do the actual compiling. It makes little sense to type out every single compile command, and then a final linker command to actually get something executable.

Answer (score 0):

So I find an answer myself, using cmake! How did I miss that..

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage